# Using Named Ranges in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data in Excel as shown in attached image where in I've used named ranges.

```
Spends.          Apr18.    May18.    Jun18
Category A.    120.        120.          120
Category B.    135.        125.           129
Category C.    110.         111.          112
```

Name Range: Spends 
Range: =Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4

The average quarterly spends are calculated using named references as:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Spends,2,2):INDEX(Spends,2,4))
```

This returns 119 in Cell E2

How can I drag this formula to subsequent cells so that it is applied automatically.

Comment: There is no "attached image" . Are you double posting the same question on different forums?

Comment: Hi, I was unable to upload image. However, the data in question is very much there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the INDEX function with constants, of course these constants will not change when you drag the formula down and/or across.

You will need to learn about absolute and relative references and use something like `Row(A1)` and/or `Column(A1)` instead of the constants 2 and 2.

But maybe it does not have to be that complicated.

You could just add a column in the data table that calculates the Average and refer to that cell.

Or, in cell E2, use the formula `=average(B2:D2)`.

I don't see the need for the named range at all in this scenario. It only complicates things.

It seems that you are struggling with appropriate data architecture concepts rather than with using formulas.

If in doubt, keep it simple. I don't see an application for copying the formula across, since you only have three months of data and you want to average these three months.

If your real scenario has more columns, then, please!!, update your question and post more relevant context. Then post a comment, so I can see you made a change.

Again, since you are new here: do not post updates into comments. Edit your question and then post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ROW() function to return the relative position

E.g. in E2 and drag down

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Spends,ROW(),2):INDEX(Spends,ROW(),4))
```

[image: Formula]

Maybe you want to dynamically find the quarter start and end columns then you can use Match function to find the dates and return the position (column) where found. Then feed these into your formula:

Getting the columns by searching for qtr start and end:

[image: Columns]

Referencing those found positions as column arguments in your formula:

[image: Formula with column arguments]